# Eigen values of a nilpotent matrix over a finite field?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields, nilpotence

If $A$ is a nilpotent matrix over a field of characteristics $0$, then all eigen values of $A$ are $0$. Does the same result holds even for the nilpotent matrices over a finite field?

Comment: Yes: the same result holds over finite fields

Comment: Any proof why? By cayley Hamilton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obviously true over *any* field. Say $A^n=0$ and $Ax=\lambda x$, $x\ne0$. Then $\lambda^n x=A^nx=0$, so $\lambda^n=0$, hence $\lambda=0$. I can't imagine a proof that depends on the field having characteristic zero...

What about the converse? The converse is less trivial, but it doesn't require Cayley-Hamilton.

Of course the converse is false in general: The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ has $0$ as its only real eigenvalue but it's not nilpotent.

**Assume** below we're talking about operators on a finite-dimensional vector space over an *algebraically closed* field. And let $\sigma(T)$ denote the set of eigenvalues of $T$.

> > **Lemma** If $p$ is a polynomial and $\lambda\in \sigma(p(T))$ then there exists $\alpha\in\sigma(T)$ with $p(\alpha)=\lambda$.

Proof: There exist $\alpha_j$ with $p(x)-\lambda=\prod(x-\alpha_j)$. So $p(T)-\lambda I=\prod(T-\alpha_jI)$; hence there exists $j$ such that $T-\alpha_jI$ is not invertible.

> > **Theorem** If $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$ then $T$ is nilpotent.

Proof: Say $T:V\to V$. Say $N$ is the kernel of $T$. If $N=Y$ we're done; suppose not and let $W=V/N$.
Now $T$ induces an operator $\tilde T:W\to W$ and $\tilde T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$. This says that there exists $x\in V$ with $x\ne 0$ and $y\in N$ such that $$Tx=\lambda x+y.$$
It follows that $\lambda=0$, because if $\lambda\ne0$ then $$T(x+\lambda^{-1}y)=\lambda(x+\lambda^{-1}y),$$so $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

So $Tx=y$, which says that the nullspace of $T^2$ is a proper superspace of the nullspace of $T$. The lemma shows that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T^2$. Repeating the argument shows that there exists $n$ such that $T^{2^n}=0$.

Comment: The converse can be neatly shown via Cayley-Hamilton

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't see why you'd need C-H for the converse. If $\lambda x=Ax$, $x\ne 0$ and also $\lambda\ne0$ then $A^nx\ne0$, hence $A^n\ne0$.

Comment: So if $A$ has only zero eigenvalues, then how do you show that $A^nx = 0$ for **all** $x$ (as opposed to just the eigenvectors)?

Comment: Hmm, you said converse and I gave the contrapositive, sorry.

Comment: It seems clear that the converse does not hold over any field. Also you probably want to state carefully exactly what you mean by "the converse". If $T(x,y,z)=(-y,x,0)$ then all the (real) eigenvalues of $T$ equal zero but $T$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose we should say that $T$ has $0$ as its only eigenvalue when taken as a linear transformation over a vector space over the *algebraic completion* of the field in question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, it seems to me that if the field is algebraically complete then there's no problem with what "the converse" is, and in that case then yes, seems to me the converse is true, and probably does require Caley-Hamilton (or some other not quite trivial result).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, the converse does not require Cayley-Hamilton. See edit.